# How to render a template from controller within template -- Java, Play 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, scala-template

Is it possible to call a controller method to render a template within a template?
Or is that totally the wrong aproach?

In the div container there is only a sting displayed but not the redered html from my productTable template.

The displayed string inside the `<div class="products">`:

```
SimpleResult(200, Map(Content-Type -> text/html; charset=utf-8))
```

Template:

```
@categories.map {cat =>
<div>some html</div>
<div class="products">@controller.Products.getByCatergoyId(cat.id)</div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public static Result getByCatergoyId(Long catId) {
List<Product> products = Product.find.where().eq("category.id", catId).findList();
return ok(views.html.display.productTable.render(products));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the code from the productTable view your method shouldn't return a `Result` but just a `String` containing rendered code.... aaaannnyyyyway , there is definitely much better way for rendering sub-templates in Play, check the [**Tags**](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaTemplateUseCases) section of the documentation it does exactly what you want directly from the view, of course you will need to pass a product object to it.

Just create `tags` package in your `view` package and add there your sub-template (responsible for rendering only pat of page) it behaves exactly the same as common template.